# FormData Object Parsing Only One Input

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a FormData object which I create using a form's ID. This form has multiple input values. I then send the FormData using an XMLHttpRequest().

However in the request (which I have debugged using Google Chrome's Developer Tool) I can see that in form data, when I view the "parsed" version its only sending the first input value. However when I view the source of the FormData all input values are there.

**My Question**

Why when viewing the parsed version of `FormData` can I only see one value whereas viewing the source I can see all of them?

This may be the cause of other issues on the server end as its not retrieving any of the parameters correctly.

**EDIT** - Some Code

*Form*

```
<form id='properties'>
    <input type='text' name='name' value='previous'/>
    <input type='text' name='occupation' value='unknown'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='ID' value='23'/>
</form>
```

*Javascript XMLHttpRequest Method*

```
function sendRequest() {
        var request = getHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (request.readyState==4 && request.status == 200) {
            console.log("Received Response: "+request.response);
        }
    }
    request.open("POST","resort-service.php",true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var form = new FormData(document.getElementById("properties"))
    request.send(form);
}
```

*Google Chrome Developer Tool* - Used to debug the `XMLHttpRequest` after its sent and the response.

Parsed Data:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary94v9BnBjfFvkLOzw
Content-Disposition: form-data; name:"name"

previous
------WebKitFormBoundary94v9BnBjfFvkLOzw
Content-Disposition: form-data; name
```

Source Data:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary94v9BnBjfFvkLOzw
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

previous
------WebKitFormBoundary94v9BnBjfFvkLOzw
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="occupation"

unknown
------WebKitFormBoundary94v9BnBjfFvkLOzw
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ID"

23
```

Comment: Can you post some source code? without it this is very hard to diagnose.

Comment: @scunliffe added some code

Answer (score 0):

After some more hunting around on the internet I found the solution.

The error was this line.

```
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

After removing this line it was being transferred just fine.